# Inheritance of from_<type> in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, overloading

**Edit: There was some confusion, but I want to ask a general question about object oriented design in Python.**

Consider a class that lets you map data values to counts or frequencies:

```
class DataMap(dict):
    pass
```

Now consider a subclass that allows you to construct a histogram from a list of data:

```
class Histogram(DataMap):
    def __init__(self, list_of_values):
        # 1. Put appropriate super(...) call here if necessary
        # 2. Build the map of values to counts in self
        pass
```

Now consider a class that lets you make a smoothed probability mass table rather than a `Histogram`.

```
class ProbabilityMass(DataMap):
    pass
```

What is the *best way* to allow a `ProbabilityMass` to be constructed from either a `Histogram` or a list of values?

I "grew up" programming in C++, and in this case I would use an overloaded constructor. In Python I've thought of doing this with:

- The constructor takes multiple arguments (all but one of these should == None)
- I define from_Histogram and from_list methods

In the second case (which I believe is better), what is the best way to allow the `from_list` method to use the shared code from the `Histogram` constructor? A `ProbabilityMass` table is nearly identical to a `Histogram` table, but it is scaled so that the sum of all value is 1.0.

**If you have come across a similar problem, please share your expertise!**

Comment: Oliver, this question has been asked other times, although I'm having a hard time coming up with the right keywords to find them right now. Basically, use a `staticmethod` which calls the constructor as an alternate constructor.

Comment: @agf Should I define two static methods (ProbabilityMass.from_list and ProbabilityMass.from_histogram)? Or should one of them use the __init__ method? Or maybe there is some "constructor overloading" machinery or standard I don't know about (perhaps this is what you mean by "alternate constructor")?

Comment: If one is clearly the "Default" / most generic one, use that as `__init__`. If neither is, you could pick one to be `__init__`, or you could just factor out the common code into `__init__` and have both static methods call that after doing pre-processing. (Make sure to note in the docstring not to call the constructor directly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, if you think you want `@staticmethod`, you almost always don't.  Either the function is not part of the class, in which case it should just be a free function, or it is part of the class, but not tied to an instance, and it should be a `@classmethod`.  Your named constructor is a good candidate for a `@classmethod`.

Also note that you should invoke `A.__init__` from `B` via `super()`, otherwise multiple inheritance can bite you bad.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.values_to_counts = {}
        for val in data:
            if val in self.values_to_counts:
                self.values_to_counts[val] += 1
            else:
                self.values_to_counts[val] = 1
    @classmethod
    def from_values_to_counts(cls, values_to_counts):
        self = cls([])
        self.values_to_counts = values_to_counts
        return self

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, data, parameter):
        super(B, self).__init__(data)
        self.parameter = parameter
    def print_parameter(self):
        print self.parameter
```

In this case, you don't need a `B.from_values_to_counts`, it inherits from `A`, and it will return an instance of `B`, since that's how it was called.

If you need to do more complex initialization in `B`, you can, using `super()`, which looks very similar to the way it would when you use it with instances.  after all, a `classmethod` really isn't anything more complex than an `instancemethod` where the `im_self` attribute is assigned to the class itself.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.values_to_counts = {}
        for val in data:
            if val in self.values_to_counts:
                self.values_to_counts[val] += 1
            else:
                self.values_to_counts[val] = 1
    @classmethod
    def from_values_to_counts(cls, values_to_counts):
        self = cls([])
        self.values_to_counts = values_to_counts
        return self

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, data, parameter):
        super(B, self).__init__(data)
        self.parameter = parameter
    def print_parameter(self):
        print self.parameter
    @classmethod
    def from_values_to_counts(cls, values_to_counts):
        self = super(B, cls).from_values_to_counts(values_to_counts)
        do_more_initialization(self)
        return self
```

Comment: Nice. Might want to add the missing `return` to `from_values_to_counts` (I know this is just an example, but don't want to mislead anyone).

Comment: "In this case, you don't need a B.from_values_to_counts, it inherits from A" I want a from_values_to_counts_and_parameter method. That method does two things (sets the values_to_counts variable and the parameter variable). I am aware of class methods (they're mentioned in the post); I was also hoping to address the problem in general. for a data structure like a probability mass table (which could be defined by a list of values or by a histogram), what is the best way to define constructors or static/class methods?

Comment: +1 @tokenmacguy class methods did the trick-- but it was quite tricky to decide what code to put where (init, class method 1, class method 2)!